# Multiple select2 returning only a single selection on form submit

Tags: php, jquery-select2

I am using multiple select2 in one of the forms. After submitting a form, in the backend, only the single selected value is fetched whereas multiple options are selected.

**HTML**

```
<form id="test" method="POST">
    <select name="dps_days_to[NL]" class="dokan-form-control dps_days_selection" required  multiple="multiple">
        <option></option>
        <option value="0">Sunday</option>
        <option value="1">Monday</option>
        <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4">Thurday</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    jQuery('.dps_days_selection').select2({
    placeholder: "Please select a day"
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
var_dump($_POST['dps_days_to']);
```

**RESULT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

For example: if Sunday & Monday are selected from available options in select2 multiple dropdown, only the value of options Monday is returned (i.e, 1)

Please, can someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Himani

If you want to get data as per name `dps_days_to[NL]`, you can make changes as per below.
**Declare [NL] as Array[] i.e.  dps_days_to[NL][] , so it can store multiple values.**

If [NL] is fixed everytime, then this works.

```
<select name="dps_days_to[NL][]" class="dokan-form-control dps_days_selection" required  multiple="multiple">
```

**RESULT**

```
[dps_days_to] => Array
(
    [NL] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this fixed my issue :)

Comment: @Himani You are welcome Himani. I am glad that you got your desired solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure,

```
<select name="dps_days_to[NL][]" class="dokan-form-control dps_days_selection" required  multiple="multiple" class="days_selection">
```

here you are mentioning **class attributes multiple times**.
merge it to one and once check.

> **Or you can try giving starting values from 1 instead of 0**

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo. Removing the extra class name doesn't fixes the issue. Please can you tell me what do you mean by "Or you can try giving starting values from 1 instead of 0" ?

Comment: Hey, the issue has been fixed indeed!

Comment: I have one more question, If I adjust the name dps_days_to[] to dps_days_to[NL] then only a single selection is returned.

Comment: I have made changes. Check now.