# Select2 with multiple selections enabled only returns a single selection upon form submission

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jquery-select2, werkzeug

I am using a Select2 dropdown in my HTML form. The HTML for that looks like

```
<select required id="item-search" name="items[]" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
```

The JavaScript to activate the Select2 looks like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(() => {
       $('#item-search').select2({
            placeholder: "sample",
            maximumSelectionLength: 10,
            ajax: {
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/validate",
                dataType: "json",
                data: function (params) {
                    var query = {
                        search: params.term,
                        email: "{{email}}"
                    }
                    return query;
                },
            },
            minimumInputLength: 1,
        });
     }
   </script>
```

But on my Flask backend, the request body for this form contains a key for the Select2 items[], but the value is simply a string rather than a comma separated list of IDs.

```
'items[]': '1'
```

I had 3 different items selected with IDs 1, 2, and 3. It is only returning the first.

I have tried:

- Using a class instead of an ID to identify the Select2
- Using a name of `items[][]`
- A different name such as `tags[]`
- Removing the `required` attribute
- Different selection combinations
- Temporarily using hard-coded `<option>` instead of those returned by the server

I have also read through the Select2 docs, and this was [one of the most basic examples](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage). I also read the following stack overflow posts:

- [select2 multi-value only sending one value in POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458499/select2-multi-value-only-sending-one-value-in-post)
- [Multiple select2 returning only a single selection on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555823/multiple-select2-returning-only-a-single-selection-on-form-submit)

I've run out of ideas as to what might be going wrong here. I'm considering resorting to writing the selections to the DOM as inputs by binding to a Select2 event, and including that with the form. But I'd much prefer to get this working the right way and figure out this puzzle.

**Found the solution**
The frontend was totally fine. Flask was automatically casting the form data to key value pairs of strings, which when applied to an array just stringifies the first element in the array as the value to that key. The solution to get the full array uncasted in Flask is to call `request.form.getlist('items[]')`. I found this in the Werkzeug documentation [here](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist)

Comment: [Works for me on node](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-27wbon?file=index.js). Maybe the issue is with how you send the files to the server or the server itself. Test by console.log `$('#item-search').val()` right after you select option, you can see the option you selected

Comment: Good point. That JQuery yields all 3 IDs as an array. So in the browser I tried using the network tab to view the request. According to the browser, the payload being sent is the array of IDs, so I'm not sure how Flask is casting that to a string. Going to focus my debugging efforts on the server side now.

Comment: Adding [this](https://gist.github.com/devdave/1472832) to my HTML form for testing further confirms that Flask seems to be unable to parse arrays in an HTML form.

Comment: Flask docs [indicate](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=request#flask.Request.form) that the `request.form` is a dict that accepts strings as keys and values. So it must be casting the array value to a string. 
Looks like I may be able to [reconfigure](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=request#flask.Request.parameter_storage_class) this though.

Comment: You are not showing how you retrieve the form values from Flask. But I suggest you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40566757/6843158).